# Exception when using Context.SaveChanges

Tags: c#, sql-insert, informix

I am currently learning how to interact with an external database in Visual Studios via C#.

I have a table named Notetext with a column 'Id' and a column 'Text'.

I want to insert a new line with the program, but every time the program stops at
'context.SaveChanges' and shows the error message:

`IBM.Data.Db2.DB2Exception: "External component has thrown an exception."`

**Info: I use DBMS Informix from IBM**

My current code looks like this:

```
namespace Notebook.Models
{
    public partial class Notetext
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
private void InsertIntoButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using var context = new NotebookContext();

    // Database table Notetext
    var note = new Notetext
    {
        Id = 10,
        Text = "This is the test text",
    };

    context.Notetexts.Add(note);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I kept changing and trying a few things, but obviously not the right ones.

---

*Don't mind my english, not my native language.*

Comment: Have you set a connection to the database?

Comment: Yes, I have. I can also read and output already existing data from the database. I just can't manage to insert new data or modify data again.

Comment: this might be caused by insufficient rights on the database end, make sure the database allows update and insert actions on the user you connect to the database with.

Comment: Check the inner exceptions if any and make sure you can actually specify a value for the Id column (it could be an identity).

Comment: @Roe, sorry for late response; I have all the permissions to make changes on the database.

Comment: @Luis_Erschig have you looked at the inner exception, it should specify what error has occured. If you could provide the text of the inner exception I might be able to help you further

Comment: When I open the details of the exception, the value of the InnerException is null. But I can give you the ExceptionMessage, maybe that helps for now:                                 To evaluate the System.Exception.get_Message method, the System.Reflection.Assembly.IsRuntimeImplemented method must be called, which cannot be called in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much trial and error, I finally managed to solve my problem.
In fact, it was caused by an in-house requirement for the creation of a new database in our DBMS that not everyone knew existed.

However, I'll post my solution here on Stack Overflow in case anyone else might encounter a problem like this.

Solution:

> CREATE DATABASE name_of_db **IN dbse01 WITH LOG**;